Probability distribution for the perimeter of a random triangle in a circle
This is the same question as this question except that the random triangles do not need to necessarily touch the circle and I am only interested in the distribution for the perimeter. And I am interested in the exact closed form for the PDF, if that is possible even though it would be complicated.
Here are 4 random examples:

For the case when the $r=1$, the maximum perimeter is still the same, namely $3\sqrt{3}$
When I ran $100000$ trials I got a distribution that looks like:

With the corrected code, the expected value is simply the same as what was mentioned in the comments, namely, $\frac{128}{15\pi}$. The empirical results matched it.
For all the related problems of finding the geometric probabilities, the pdf's have all involved the Beta distribution somehow. I don't know why.
The Mathematica code that I had used was:
 (* Clear all variables and global definitions *)
ClearAll["Global`*"]

data=Table[Perimeter[Polygon[RandomPoint[Disk[],3]]],{i,1,100000}];
Mean[data]
SmoothHistogram[data,Automatic,"PDF",Filling->Axis]


The way you get $p_3$ is curiously intricate. Is it supposed to be uniformly distributed within the circle? Shouldn't the answer be three times the length of a random segment within the circle? We souldn't bother with three segments.

Yes. I wasn't sure how to do it to make sure it is uniform. I have a weird compulsion to try and not use branching statements. I don't know if it is possible to generate the points that fit the requirements without having to reject any.

Which requirements? Three points always make a triangle, don't they?

Three points do not always make a triangle. For example if they are collinear.

@ClaudeChaunier I am not sure it is 3 times the length of a random segment. I can't think of how to prove that. Heuristically it makes sense. If I know the expected value, I can get a better approximation for the pdf in Mathematica.

@TegLouis Three points always make a triangle if they are not collinear. With probability 1, three random points in the unit disk are not collinear. Also, by linearity of expectation, the expected value of the perimeter is equal to three times the expected length of a random segment.

I believe the reason this doesn't match your simulation is that the answer there is for three points uniformly chosen in the circle, and your third point isn't uniform.

@KevinP.Costello Code and expected value is corrected. Thank you.

I can't see what use can this have. Maybe it's a part of another problem you work on. But if it's just for fun then there is a more beautiful similar problem: to find the PDF of a random triangle area on lobachevsky plane

Very minor Mathematica point: your use of the Table function doesn't actually invoke the index i, so you can just do Table[code,100000]. Also, a relevant article on this would seem to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.0261.

If one computes the average distance between two such randomly distributed points (rather than three), then is the answer of this problem $3$ times of that?

@Euclid For the expected value, yes. One of the comments says it is because of the linearity of expectation. Simulations support that.

@Semiclassical You are correct for both.

@TegLouis thanks. and for the distribution, if one obtains the distribution for a single line segment, then the perimeter could be computed by convolution due to independence, right?

@МаратРамазанов It is part of a much larger experimental mathematics problem.

The lengths AB, BC, CA are only two by two independent. The perimeter is not the cube convolution of the distribution of $AB.$
